# Collect logs from clients of flavours of system

Tags: logging, flume, fluentd

I am trying to get logs securely. There are machines in public domain from where I need to get logs (windows / linux flavors) and I intend to make use of a framework like Flume / FluentD.

Any idea if this is doable in secure way?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Fluentd, take a look at the [secure forward plugin](http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/forwarding-over-ssl)